# Updating a component's state that is an array causes some values to be lost

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-hooks

I'm trying to make a component display a loading screen until all images have been loaded. I'm doing this because there are about 25 images that I need to make sure have finished loading before I display the page.

My solution is to use the `onLoadingComplete` prop of `next/image`, and store an id of all images in a state that is an array of numbers. My code:

```js
{(selectedActivity ? selectedActivity.images : calloutSet.allImages).map(imageReference => (
    <div key={imageReference.id} className={styles.symbol}>
        <div className={styles.symbolImageContainer}>
            <Image
                fill={true}
                priority={true}
                onLoadingComplete={() => {
                    if (!loadedImages.includes(imageReference.id)) {
                        setLoadedImages([...loadedImages, imageReference.id])
                    }
                }}
                sizes="10rem, (max-width: 600px) 7.5rem"
                className={styles.symbol}
                src={imageReference.url}
                alt='Callout Set Symbol'
            />
        </div>
    </div>
))}
```

The problem with this approach is that I believe `onLoadingComplete` is being called multiple times simultaneously, causing the array to "lose" some values. I've done some print tests to confirm this (the "loaded" console log was placed right before `setLoadedImages`):

```
loaded 0
loaded 1
loaded 2
loaded 3
loaded 4
loaded 5
loaded 6
loaded 7
loaded 8
loaded 9
loaded 11
loaded 10
loaded 12
loaded 13
loaded 14
loaded 15
loadedImages: [10, 12, 15]
```

I'm not sure how to fix this issue, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When updating the state, based on previous state multiple times, the new state contains the original previous state + current update, but not other updates that happened in the same render phase. To solve that use an [updater function](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state) when setting the state:

```
setLoadedImages(prev => [...prev , imageReference.id])
```

You can also simplify some of the code patterns in your component by creating a function for image load.

```
const handleImageLoad = (imageId) => {
  if (!loadedImages.includes(imageId)) {
    setLoadedImages((prevLoadedImages) => [...prevLoadedImages, imageId]);
  }
};
```

And then use then pass it to component:

```
onLoadingComplete ={() => handleImageLoad(imageReference.id)}
```